# js conditional: if not false, null or undefined then

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this !! markup for anther object and it works, but here it doesn't (in one case, works in other cases).

```
if (!!slides) {
        console.log("close view clear slides")
        clearInterval(slides);
    }
```

In firebug I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: slides is not defined
```

What should my conditional be?

Comment: What `slides` is supposed to be?

Comment: Is `slides` defined? `typeof slides !== undefined`, maybe?

Comment: if its undefined, that won't work. `typeof(slides)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable if it's not defined.

```
typeof(asdf)
"undefined"

!asdf
ReferenceError: asdf is not defined

if (typeof(asdf) != "undefined") {
    // will only execute if asfd is defined.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
if (!!slides) {
```

to

```
if (!slides) {
```

Though, if slides is false, null, or undefined, then clearing it wouldn't do anything. So, maybe what you mean is

```
if (slides) {
```

?

Comment: I tried it in firebug before posting just to refresh my memory. undefined is evaluated to false. thus !undefined would evaluate to true.

Comment: `!asdf
ReferenceError: asdf is not defined`

Comment: Using a variable named 'asdf' before declaring said variable (Not defined) is different from the variable asdf containing the value undefined (Undefined).

Comment: In any case, I'm tired and skipped that one line above and then walked right into this one, heh...

Comment: Yes the two things are very different, but that's not the question.